# Running Total OVER clause, but Select Distinct instead of sum?

Tags: sql, distinct, window-functions, partition

I have the following data set:

```
|   EMAIL   |   SIGNUP_DATE   |
| A@ABC.COM |    1/1/2021     |
| B@ABC.COM |    1/2/2021     |
| C@ABC.COM |    1/3/2021     |
```

In order to find the running total of email signups as of a certain day, I ran the following sql query:

```
select 
signup_date, 
count(email) OVER (order by signup_date ASC) as running_total_signups
```

I got the following results:

```
| SIGNUP_DATE | RUNNING_TOTAL_SIGNUPS |
|   1/1/21    |           1           |
|   1/2/21    |           2           |
|   1/3/21    |           3           |
```

However for my next step, I want to be able to see not just the running total signups, but the actual signup names themselves. Therefore I want to run the same window function (count(email) OVER (order by signup_date ASC)) but instead of a count(email) just a select distinct email. This would hopefully result in the following output:

```
| SIGNUP_DATE | RUNNING_TOTAL_SIGNUPS |
|   1/1/21    |       a@abc.com       |
|   1/2/21    |       a@abc.com       |
|   1/2/21    |       b@abc.com       |
|   1/3/21    |       a@abc.com       |
|   1/3/21    |       b@abc.com       |
|   1/3/21    |       c@abc.com       |
```

How would I do this? I'm getting an error on this code:

```
select 
signup_date, 
distinct email OVER (order by signup_date ASC) as running_total_signups
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to cross-join the results and filter the joined table having a total <= to the running total:

```
with counts as (
    select *, 
      Count(*) over (order by SIGNUP_DATE asc) as tot
    from t
)
select c1.EMAIL, c1.SIGNUP_DATE
from counts c1
cross join counts c2
where c2.tot <= c1.tot
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually slightly simpler than Stu proposed:

```
select 
  x2.signup_date, 
  x1.email 
from 
  signups x1 
  INNER JOIN signups x2 ON x1.signup_date <= x2.signup_date
order by signup_date
```

If you join the table to itself but for any date that is less than or equal to, it causes a half cartesian explosion. The lowest dated row matches with only itself. The next one matches with itself and the earlier one, so one of the table aliases has its data repeated.. This continues adding more rows to the explosion as the dates increase:

[image]

In this resultset we can see we want the emails from x1, and the dates from x2

Answer (score 0):

> I want to run the same window function (count(email) OVER (order by
> signup_date ASC)) but instead of a count(email) just a select distinct
> email

Why do you want `COUNT()` window function? 
It has nothing to do with with your reqirement.

All you need is a simple self join:

```
SELECT t1.SIGNUP_DATE, t2.EMAIL 
FROM tablename t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2
ON t2.SIGNUP_DATE <= t1.SIGNUP_DATE
ORDER BY t1.SIGNUP_DATE, t2.EMAIL;
```

which will work for your sample data, but just in case there are more than 1 rows for each day in your table you should use:

```
SELECT t1.SIGNUP_DATE, t2.EMAIL 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SIGNUP_DATE FROM tablename) t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2
ON t2.SIGNUP_DATE <= t1.SIGNUP_DATE
ORDER BY t1.SIGNUP_DATE, t2.EMAIL;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=be9500b32f184b57c6626a9d9feca6ea).